# How to implement registration in Kamailio with WebRTC?

Tags: websocket, webrtc, sip, kamailio

I've configured Kamailio for WebRTC calls. Registration is successful, but when I try to call, response "478 Unresolvable destination" comes back.

Generally I can say, that my SIP proxy responds, but can't contact a client based on its URI - also, I successfuly ping clients with "kamcmd ws.ping", but cannot with "kamctl ping". I am not sure, but I think that the problem is within registration, where nathelper should take place with fix_nated_register() function, but there is not any sign that it did. I am using standart configuration for websocket and TLS connection.

I tried both JsSIP and sipML5 - only local network connection.

## This should do what's needed in my kamailio.cfg:

modparam("nathelper|registrar", "received_avp", "$avp(RECEIVED)")

request_route {
        route(REQINIT);

```
  if (nat_uac_test(64)) {
            force_rport();
            if (is_method("REGISTER")) ###<--here
                    fix_nated_register();
            else {
                    if (!add_contact_alias()) {
                            xlog("L_ERR", "Error aliasing contact <$ct>\n");modparam("nathelper|registrar", "received_avp", "$avp(RECEIVED)")
                            sl_send_reply("400", "Bad Request");
                            exit;
                    }
            }
    }
```

...

## And here is what is saved to user location database:

```
                "Contact":  {
                  "Address":  "sip:oq1n4lu1@38gn0ph6h558.invalid;transport=ws",
                  "Expires":  577,
                  "Q":  -1,
                  "Call-ID":  "uefjkjk5cdatcdgg333vo8",
                  "CSeq": 8,
                  "User-Agent": "JsSIP 3.2.15",
                  "Received": "[not set]",
                  "Path": "[not set]",
                  "State":  "CS_NEW",
                  "Flags":  0,
                  "CFlags": 0,
                  "Socket": "tls:192.168.2.224:4443",
                  "Methods":  6943,
                  "Ruid": "uloc-5c66ecbf-974-1",
                  "Instance": "<urn:uuid:4dd03beb-8241-49fc-81f6-db0d895fde87>",
                  "Reg-Id": 1,
                  "Server-Id":  0,
                  "Tcpconn-Id": 2,
                  "Keepalive":  0,
                  "Last-Keepalive": 1550250947,
                  "Last-Modified":  1550250947
```

fix_nated_register() should copy actual source IP address and port to Received header in the user location, and send Received parameter in Contact header in the 200 OK within REGISTER dialog, but it doesn't either. 
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Can suggest read source code of some kamailio-based softswitch. For example this is one of the best open https://github.com/2600hz/kazoo-configs-kamailio/tree/master/kamailio

Comment: I've solved it, it was really tragic spelling mistake in #ifdef syntax, hardly detectable misfortunately. Thanks anyway, I'll look it over for further enhancements.